# Are there any other significant radii around Schwarzschild black holes besides the four I know of?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, orbital-motion, event-horizon

A Schwarzschild (non-rotating, non-charged) black hole has an event horizon with radius $r_s = \frac{2 G M} {c^2}$, where $M$ is the mass of the black hole, $G$ is the gravitational constant, and $c$ is the speed of light. I know of three additional significant radii:

- Photon Sphere Radius $r_{ph} = \frac{3 G M} {c^2} = 1.5 r_s$
- Marginally-Bound Orbit Radius $r_{mb} = \frac{4 G M} {c^2} = 2 r_s$
- Innermost Stable Circular Orbit Radius $r_{isco} = \frac{6 G M} {c^2} = 3 r_s$

**Are there any other radii of note around a Schwarzschild black hole?**

Comment: See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buchdahl%27s_theorem

Comment: The Schwarzschild “radius” is defined as a reduced circumference of the horizon. The actual radius of the horizon defined as the spacelike radial distance to the origin is zero.

Answer (score 1):

There are radii that play a role when a black hole is observed from afar, for example by the [Event Horizon Telescope](https://eventhorizontelescope.org/).

For example, the event horizon appears to be $2.6r_s$ because the space around the black hole is not flat, and rays reaching the observer may emanate from the "rear side" of the horizon.  See for example this [nice video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zUyH3XhpLTo) at around 3:30.

Comment: This is not the apparent event horizon. It is a projection of the photon ring at $1.5r_s$. No rays reach the observer from behind the black hole if they originate from or travel within this radius.